# Invoking a pop-up 'confirm' message box in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know how to this when a button is clicked. For example:

```
imgBtnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Please confirm you want to delete the letter')")
```

My question is:

Say I have a piece of code-behind not related to clicking,calculating the value of a boolean, and if the boolean is true then I want the message box with ok/cancel to appear.

f.e.:

```
bool hasMoney = ...

if (hasMoney)
{
\\message box..
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Do you want to still add onclick attribute even if the boolean value is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private void OpenConfirmPrompt()
{
    string strScript = "<script language=JavaScript>alert('File Uploaded');</script>";

    if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("open"))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "open", strScript);
    }
}
```

And change the JS there to suit.

So call that function from a server side event.

Edit, much better explanation than me [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isstartupscriptregistered.aspx)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks!

But now there's a new question: I'm in the middle of the logic, the message box popped, and the user clicked OK/CANCEL. How do I know what he clicked so I can continue my logic accordingly??

Comment: The Ajax ConfirmButton as suggested by Phil is one way.

Otherwise your JS will have to include a do_postback http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function

This allows you to post back an arugment and a key which you can handle on page load.

Comment: My above is assuming you cant just continue your logic in pure JS

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Ajax Control Toolkit's ConfirmButton extender? Then rather than writing the JavaScript yourself, you can just set the Enabled property in your code-behind e.g.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyButton" Text="My Button" />
<ajaxtoolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender runat="server" id="MyButtonConfirmExtender" TargetControlID="MyButton" ConfirmText="Continue?" />
```

and

```
if (whatever)
{
    MyButtonConfirmExtender.Enabled = true;
}
```