# Pull request pop up a confirmation box

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

During pull request my requirement is to set a branch policy so that I can pop up a custom dialog box which will ask the user if all systems tests were run on the incoming feature branch being merged. This will possibly be a free text or a radio button kind of interaction. Is it possible to do some such custom workflows during pull requests in Azure DevOps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do some such custom workflows during pull requests
>   in Azure DevOps?

Of course yes! We provide a custom method that you can apply your idea by using `Azure Function` + `Azure Devops service hook`.

It's basic logic is write custom function scripts to achieve pop up a custom dialog box and this dialog box will ask the user some confirmation info. For [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/), we provide one feature which you can get its listen URL, and integrate it with any third party service, including **Azure devops**.

And get the listen URL of azure function, just go `Azure devops project setting` -> `Service Hooks`, create a service hook with this function URL.

The most important thing is **choose a suitable trigger event** based on your scenario conditions for azure function execution.

[image]

For detailed steps and description, check this doc: [Use Azure Functions to create custom branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be along the lines I am thinking

Comment: I have followed the article, but I don't know how to put up a message box from this Azure function in my Azure DevOps pull request workflow? Can you please share a reference?

Comment: @Chubsdad, I guess you are applying the function with C#. If this, just consider about c# message box, or make use of ajax in C#:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900975/invoking-a-pop-up-confirm-message-box-in-asp-net

Comment: I get the following error while compiling and running my azure function: 2020-01-13T09:09:03.664 [Error] run.csx(41,9): error CS0103: The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Chubsdad, do you mind create a new question with share me what the exactly code you are trying? I may help you troubleshooting with the exactly code. I would follow that ticket, and please also add the tag of C#, azure function in that question.

Comment: Sure. Please find the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713709/azure-function-for-user-confirmation-during-azure-devops-pull-request

Comment: @Chubsdad, awesome! But would have delay to give you my solution since I have another personal work now and it's very close to my off work hour.

Comment: np. I understand. It is not that urgent. Thank you.!

Comment: hi, please let me know if you need any more info from me on the new SO question that I created. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is doable at the moment but what you can do is run the tests immediately when the PR is created.

To do this create a CI Build pipeling for your master branch and add a Test task.

Then on the branch, set the Build Validation 
[image] to your CI Pipeline