# Azure function for user confirmation during Azure DevOps Pull Request

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

This questions is related to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679053/pull-request-pop-up-a-confirmation-box/59709951#59709951)

I am trying to put up a dialog box to show the author at the time a pull request is created in my Azure DevOps service. This box should be shown in the author's browser window like so:

Have you run System tests? 
  Yes
  Not applicable

Here's the code I have at the moment, just trying to show a dummy Message Box

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Windows;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
        log.Info("Service Hook Received.");

        // Get request body
        dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

        log.Info("Data Received: " + data.ToString());

        // Get the pull request object from the service hooks payload
        dynamic jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.ToString());

        // Get the pull request id
        int pullRequestId;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(jObject.resource.pullRequestId.ToString(), out pullRequestId))
        {
            log.Info("Failed to parse the pull request id from the service hooks payload.");
        };

        // Get the pull request title
        string pullRequestTitle = jObject.resource.title;

        log.Info("Service Hook Received for PR: " + pullRequestId + " " + pullRequestTitle);

        // Get the pull request text
        string checkinNotes = jObject.detailedMessage.text;
        log.Info("Checkin notes Received for PR: " + pullRequestId + " " + checkinNotes);

        MessageBox.Show("Have you run System Tests?");

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info(ex.ToString());
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

When, I compile this, I get the following error:

```
2020-01-13T09:09:03.664 [Error] run.csx(41,9): error CS0103: The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context
```

How can I modify this Azure function achieve my goal?

Comment: Add using System.windows.forms in .cs file

Comment: I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp but I don't know how to put up a message box on the pull request window in user's browser

Comment: @Chubsdad, what is the project type you choose while you create the azure function project?

Comment: Hi, I just edited it on the default editor in azure function app, just for initial experimentation

Comment: Techie is correct. Add the namespace System.windows.forms can solve this issue. BUT, System.windows.forms.dll is belong to .net framwork. It does not available for .net core

Comment: oh ok. now I understand. so, how do I solve my use case while being on dotnet core

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a native dialog window on the author's computer? Or do you have a web application in which you want to create the dialog window in?

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT: Yes, I am trying to pop up a dialog in the user's browser during the pull request completion workflow asking for some confirmation.

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT Please suggest